# I get only one class instead of two.

Tags: javascript, html

When I append this string to the browser

```
' <div class=' + (data[x].connected == true ? 'cardDefault online' : 'cardDefault offline') + ' >'
```

I get

```
<div class="cardDefault" offline> </div>
```

instead of

```
<div class="cardDefault offline" > </div>
```

Comment: You're forgetting to put quotes around the class string. You're creating HTML that looks like `<div class=cardDefault offline>` with no quotes.

Comment: Why is `cardDefault` in the ternary at all, since it's there regardless? And I have an insistent feeling that, to check against `true`, you should use `===` to ensure no type-coercion is taking place, allowing 'truthy' values to be evaluated as equal to `true`.

Comment: Ternary Operator (?) returns only one value not two..if the condition is true it returns first value if the condition is false will return the second value but not both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
' <div class="' + (data[x].connected == true ? 'cardDefault online' : 'cardDefault offline') + '">'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need quotes around the className in the output string.  Try this:

```
' <div class=\" cardDefault ' + (data[x].connected ? 'online' : 'offline') + '\" >'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
' <div class="' + (data[x].connected == true ?       'cardDefault online' : 'cardDefault offline') + '">'
```

I used double quotes around the classes.